# Is is possible to use Amazon Cognito without Amazon SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm trying to setup Amazon Cognito, and according to what it says in the console I need to sign up for Amazon SES in order to send the confirmation code and forgot password messages.

So I applied for Amazon SES access through their support center explaining that I will only be using Amazon SES in conjunction with Cognito.  I also included all the normal information they request, such as domain name, how bounces are handled, etc.

They replied denying access with this as the explanation:

> We made this decision because we believe that your use case would impact the deliverability of our service and would affect your reputation as a sender. We also want to ensure that other Amazon SES users can continue to use the service without experiencing service interruptions.

So I found this puzzling, because my understanding is that I have to signup for SES in order to have production user registration and confirmation with Amazon Cognito.

Does anyone know if we can use Cognito without SES or if there is some other way of handling this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [configure Cognito to send all emails via a Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-email-sender.html). Inside that function you can perform the email sending using any email service you want.